# IN clause on multiple columns using AND , JOIN

Tags: sql, join, in-clause

Which of the following queries are correct

```
SELECT
 ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
WHERE
 STATUS IN('OPEN','UPDATED')
AND
 ITEM_TYPE IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2')
AND
 CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
AND
 UPDATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'ZZ'
```

---

```
 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         STATUS IN('OPEN','UPDATED')
 JOIN

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         ITEM_TYPE IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2')
 JOIN

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
 JOIN

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         UPDATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'ZZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is correct, unless you want an exponential explosion of self-joins.

Comment: what I heard if UNION will return distinct rows and UNIONALL returns exponential explosin, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You're not doing a UNION, you're doing a JOIN.

Comment: I am sorry about the second QUERY, SO if I use union I should get the expected results

SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         STATUS IN('OPEN','UPDATED')
 UNION

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         ITEM_TYPE IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2')
 UNION

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
 UNION

 SELECT
         ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
 WHERE
         UPDATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'ZZ'

Comment: I very much doubt you'll get what you want.  Why won't you just do the first query, if it works?

Answer (score 0):

The first query is correct, the second would give, well....a **LOT** of reuslts.

In response to your comment, as [SQLMenace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740/sqlmenace) pointed out, use OR instead if you want to match **any** of the conditions:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
WHERE STATUS IN('OPEN','UPDATED')
   OR ITEM_TYPE IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2')
   OR CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
   OR UPDATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'ZZ'
```

Or, if you wanted to **always** restrict on the time, but meet **either** of the first conditions, then use a wrapped OR:

```
SELECT ID, STATUS, ITEM_TYPE,CREATED_TIME,UPDATED_TIME
WHERE (STATUS IN('OPEN','UPDATED') OR ITEM_TYPE IN ('ITEM1','ITEM2'))
  AND CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'YY'
  AND UPDATED_TIME BETWEEN 'XX' AND 'ZZ'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but the problem what I am encountering is if any one condition fails, query does not return any values. for example if there are no matching rows for updated_time no rows are returned even all other conditions are matching

Answer (score 0):

the first one

JOINS have to be before the WHERE clause

although you could rewrite the JOINS with EXISTS and then you cut put it in the WHERE clause

Comment: can you please provide an example